# Custom Validator Undefined Method Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting an error during runtime 'cvLeapYear_ServerValidate' is undefined

The validator is defined as

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
                 ClientValidationFunction="cvLeapYear_ServerValidate"
                 ControlToValidate="txtLeapYear" ErrorMessage="Not a leap year">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

The function

```
protected void cvLeapYear_ServerValidate(object source,ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    int year;
    try
    {
        year = Convert.ToInt32 (args.Value);
        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

is defined in the backend code and following javascript code is defined in aspx webform

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isLeapYear(sender,args)
    {
        year = parseInt(args.Value);
        if((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)||(year % 400 == 0))
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

and clientValidation function is also set.

Comment: Can you show how the validator itself is defined in the markup?

Comment: Add aspx code for "clientValidation function is also set"

Comment: @Andrei : <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="cvLeapYear_ServerValidate" ControlToValidate="txtLeapYear" ErrorMessage="Not a leap year"></asp:CustomValidator>

Comment: @Sushma, such info should be a part of the question, not just a comment. I've edited question for you, but for next question please consider adding relevant info to the question right away. And refer to Anil's answer below, as it is correct - you have messed up functions in the validator declaration.

Comment: Check the new answer added by me. Your function cvLeapYear_ServerValidate is a server side function which you can call using OnServerValidate attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="isLeapYear" ControlToValidate="txtLeapYear" ErrorMessage="Not a leap year" OnServerValidate="cvLeapYear_ServerValidate" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Add name of javascript function, as given in above code

Answer (score 0):

`ClientValidationFunction` should have the value of a javascript function which is called to validate from client side.
You have to call `isLeapYear` function.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
             ClientValidationFunction="isLeapYear"
             ControlToValidate="txtLeapYear" ErrorMessage="Not a leap year">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Your function `cvLeapYear_ServerValidate` is a server side function which you can call using `OnServerValidate` attribute.

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
             OnServerValidate ="cvLeapYear_ServerValidate"
             ControlToValidate="txtLeapYear" ErrorMessage="Not a leap year">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```